# SQL Server : combining like rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, inner-join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [WL].[Id]
  ,[WL].[UserId]
  ,[WL].[DIF]
  ,[WL].[MW]
  ,[WL].[Notes]
  ,[WL].[WDate]
  ,[WL].[CB]
  ,[WL].[MPH] 
  ,[U].[Id]
  ,[U].[UserName]
  ,[U].[We]
  ,[U].[SLength]
  ,[U].[UP]
  ,[U].[PU]
  ,[U].[ANumber]
  ,[U].[G_CK]
FROM 
    [Wsite].[dbo].[WLog] as WL 
INNER JOIN 
    [Wsite].[dbo].[Users] AS U ON [U].[Id] = [WL].[UserId] 
WHERE 
    [WL].[WDate] >= CONVERT(datetime, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 120)  
    AND [WL].[WDate] <= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 120)
GROUP BY 
    [WL].[UserId]
```

And the error I get is:

> Column 'Wsite.dbo.WLog.Id' is invalid in the select
>   list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or
>   the GROUP BY clause.

What I want is to just combine the data if there are more than one `UserID` in the list.

As an example:

```
Id  | UserId | .... | Id   | UserName    | SLength | ....
5843| 99304  | .... | 99304| Bob Barker  | 14      | ....
5844| 06300  | .... | 06300| Dean Martin | 104     | ....
5845| 99304  | .... | 99304| Bob Barker  | 8       | ....
5846| 99304  | .... | 99304| Bob Barker  | 11      | ....
5847| 7699   | .... | 7699 | John Doe    | 0       | ....
```

So it should look like this:

```
Id  | UserId | .... | Id   | UserName    | SLength | ....
5843| 99304  | .... | 99304| Bob Barker  | 33      | ....
5844| 06300  | .... | 06300| Dean Martin | 104     | ....
5847| 7699   | .... | 7699 | John Doe    | 0       | ....
```

Notice that *Bob Barker's* **SLength** was combined (14+8+11=33).

Any help would be great! Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   MIN([WL].[Id]) AS [WLID]
  ,MIN([WL].[UserId]) AS [WLUD]
  ,SUM([WL].[DIF]) AS [DIF]
  ,SUM([WL].[MW]) AS [MW]
  ,[WL].[Notes]
  ,[WL].[WDate]
  ,SUM([WL].[CB]) AS [CB]
  ,SUM([WL].[MPH])  AS [MPH]
  ,MIN([U].[Id] AS [UID]
  ,MIN([U].[UserName] AS [UUserName]
  ,[U].[We]
  ,SUM([U].[SL]) AS [SL]
  ,[U].[UP]
  ,[U].[PU]
  ,[U].[ANumber]
  ,[U].[G_CK]
  FROM [Wsite].[dbo].WLog as WL 
INNER JOIN [Wsite].[dbo].[Users] AS U 
    ON [U].[Id] = [WL].[UserId] 
 WHERE [WL].[WDate] >= CONVERT(datetime, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 120)  
   AND [WL].[WDate] <= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 120)
GROUP BY 
   [WL].[Notes]
  ,[WL].[WDate]
  ,[U].[We]
  ,[U].[UP]
  ,[U].[PU]
  ,[U].[ANumber]
  ,[U].[G_CK]
ORDER BY [U].[UserName] DESC
```

Comment: Are all of the other fields going to contain the same data for besides the `Id` field and the `SLength` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use GROUP BY, it means you want to group like elements together and present some sort of aggregate (COUNT, SUM, MIN, etc.) of the remaining items you want to display. Becaus eof this, if you include [WL].[Id] in the select list, you'll basically get the full selection without any aggregation (since [WL].[Id] is unique).

You'll need to do something like the following:

```
SELECT MIN([WL].[Id]) AS ID
  ,[WL].[UserId]
  ,[U].[Id]
  ,[U].[UserName]
  ,SUM([SLength]) AS SLength
FROM [Wsite].[dbo].[WLog] as WL 
INNER JOIN [Wsite].[dbo].[Users] AS U 
        ON [U].[Id] = [WL].[UserId] 
     WHERE [WL].[WDate] >= CONVERT(datetime, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 120)  
       AND [WL].[WDate] <= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 120)
  GROUP BY [WL].[UserId]
  ,[U].[Id]
  ,[U].[UserName]
```

(For brevity, I did not include all the fields).

Also note that since [WL].[Id] appears to be unique, it is meaningless in this context, unless you want to display its first occurance (then you can add MIN([WL].[Id]) to the SELECT list).

Comment: That doesn't seem to combine them?

Comment: Which doesn't combine what where? Please provide details.

Comment: The UserName still shows up more than once. It's not being combined together.

Comment: Please add your updated query- most likely you are including a unique field (like [WL].[Id]), that will suppress aggregation. See my note on my answer.

Comment: Again- read my note about [WL].[Id]. If you include it in the select list, you will NOT get the grouping you are wanting. Either remove it from the list, or use an aggregate function of its values. To be clear- the SELECT list (non-aggregated fields) are those fields which are duplicated across the data. From the data you showed, [WL].[Id] seems to be unique values. I updated my answer to include [WL].[Id] with a MIN aggregation.

Comment: OK again i updated my OP to show this. Still does not combine them.

Comment: Take out the DISTINCT- GROUP BY will take care of that. Look at your resulting data in the non-aggregate fields. Whatever data is not the same across all the fields you want to group by, you need to either remove it from the list or aggregate it. MIN([U].[UserName] AS [UUserName]- NO!! That is one of the fields you want to GROUP BY. Go back to my original answer and do NOT add any additional fields. Does that give you the summation you're looking for? Then start adding fields one by one and determine if each field should be grouped or aggregated.

Comment: Yes, stripping out the other fields and leaving the default as you show does work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `GROUP BY`, then any columns that are not in the grouping have to be aggregated in some way (`SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`, etc)

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   [WL].[Id]
  ,[WL].[UserId]
  ,[WL].[DIF]
  ,[WL].[MW]
  ,[WL].[Notes]
  ,[WL].[WDate]
  ,[WL].[CB]
  ,[WL].[MPH] 
  ,Sum ([U].[SLength]) SLength
FROM [Wsite].[dbo].[WLog] as WL 
INNER JOIN [Wsite].[dbo].[Users] AS U 
    ON [U].[Id] = [WL].[UserId] 
WHERE [WL].[WDate] >= CONVERT(datetime, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 120)  
    AND [WL].[WDate] <= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 120)
GROUP BY 
   [WL].[Id]
  ,[WL].[UserId]
  ,[WL].[DIF]
  ,[WL].[MW]
  ,[WL].[Notes]
  ,[WL].[WDate]
  ,[WL].[CB]
  ,[WL].[MPH]
```

Here are the aggregate functions you can use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx

Comment: Just like @Dave Jemiison, the UserName still shows up more than once. It's not being combined together

Comment: I took out some of the columns and edited the query.  Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but this might work in your case.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [WL].[Id]
  ,[WL].[UserId]
  ,[WL].[DIF]
  ,[WL].[MW]
  ,[WL].[Notes]
  ,[WL].[WDate]
  ,[WL].[CB]
  ,[WL].[MPH] 
  ,[U].[Id]
  ,[U].[UserName]
  ,[U].[We]
  ,SUM([U].[SLength]) OVER (PARTITION BY [WL].[UserId])
  ,[U].[UP]
  ,[U].[PU]
  ,[U].[ANumber]
  ,[U].[G_CK]
          FROM [Wsite].[dbo].[WLog] as WL 
    INNER JOIN [Wsite].[dbo].[Users] AS U 
            ON [U].[Id] = [WL].[UserId] 
         WHERE [WL].[WDate] >= CONVERT(datetime, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 120)  
           AND [WL].[WDate] <= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 120)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your use of `GROUP BY` is not correct. All the columns used in your `SELECT` should be either in the `GROUP BY` clause or should be Aggregate functions.
Your query should be something like below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT MIN([WL].[Id]) [Id]
    ,[WL].[UserId]
    ,[WL].[DIF]
    ,[WL].[MW]
    ,[WL].[Notes]
    ,[WL].[WDate]
    ,[WL].[CB]
    ,[WL].[MPH] 
    ,[U].[Id]
    ,[U].[UserName]
    ,[U].[We]
    ,SUM([U].[SLength]) SLength
    ,[U].[UP]
    ,[U].[PU]
    ,[U].[ANumber]
    ,[U].[G_CK]
FROM [Wsite].[dbo].[WLog] as WL 
    INNER JOIN [Wsite].[dbo].[Users] AS U 
        ON [U].[Id] = [WL].[UserId] 
WHERE [WL].[WDate] >= CONVERT(datetime, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 120)  
       AND [WL].[WDate] <= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 120)
GROUP BY [WL].[UserId]
    ,[WL].[DIF]
    ,[WL].[MW]
    ,[WL].[Notes]
    ,[WL].[WDate]
    ,[WL].[CB]
    ,[WL].[MPH] 
    ,[U].[Id]
    ,[U].[UserName]
    ,[U].[We]
    ,[U].[UP]
    ,[U].[PU]
    ,[U].[ANumber]
    ,[U].[G_CK]
```

Comment: It looks like [WL].[Id] is an identity field, so including in the select list will cause all the results to display without aggregation.